# max-width resize on SVG doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css, svg, sass, scroll

I would like to set a class when scrolling and then define the SVG size. I want to define the size with max-width, but the whole thing doesn't work in Firefox. In Chrome it works without problems. Anyone an idea why this does not work?

The problem exists only in Firefox - Chrome and other browsers work fine with max-width. And it is only a problem with SVG.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 20) {
        $(".logo").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
        $(".logo").removeClass("fixed");
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.logo svg {
  max-width: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: max-width 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1), width 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
}
.logo.fixed svg {
  max-width: 220px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: max-width 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1), width 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo img-responsive pull-left">    <a href="/">

<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 4544.2 1409.6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 4544.2 1409.6;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);}
    .st1{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);}
    .st2{clip-path:url(#SVGID_6_);}
    .st3{clip-path:url(#SVGID_8_);}
</style>
<polygon points="3885.9,643.6 3885.9,11.6 4210.1,11.6 4210.1,106.1 3997,106.1 3997,274.1 4188.1,274.1 4188.1,366.5 3997,366.5 
    3997,549.1 4222.7,549.1 4222.7,643.6 "></polygon>
<rect x="4362.2" y="11.6" width="112.3" height="632"></rect>
<rect x="567.6" y="11.6" width="112.3" height="632"></rect>
<g>
    <defs>
        <rect id="SVGID_1_" width="4474.5" height="660.4"></rect>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
    </clipPath>
    <path class="st0" d="M1011.4,655.1c-70.3,0-129.1-12.6-184.7-37.7l35.7-96.6c42,20,90.2,37.8,139.5,37.8
        c68.2,0,110.3-26.2,110.3-82.9c0-45.2-32.6-65.1-79.8-87.2l-90.2-41.9c-68.2-31.5-116.5-73.5-116.5-167
        C825.6,65.1,925.3,0,1037.6,0c62.9,0,104.9,11.6,159.5,33.6l-36.7,92.4c-36.7-15.7-72.4-31.5-116.4-31.5
        c-58.8,0-110.2,22-110.2,78.7c0,42,29.3,59.8,66.1,76.6l93.4,43c77.6,35.7,128,81.9,128,161.7
        C1221.2,570.1,1140.4,655.1,1011.4,655.1"></path>
    <polygon class="st0" points="285.5,107.1 285.5,643.6 173.2,643.6 173.2,107.1 0,107.1 0,11.6 459.6,11.6 459.6,107.1  "></polygon>
</g>
<g>
    <defs>
        <rect id="SVGID_3_" width="4474.5" height="660.4"></rect>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
    </clipPath>
    <polygon class="st1" points="2843.3,643.6 2843.3,11.6 3167.5,11.6 3167.5,106.1 2954.6,106.1 2954.6,274.1 3145.5,274.1 
        3145.5,366.5 2954.6,366.5 2954.6,549.1 3180.2,549.1 3180.2,643.6    "></polygon>
    <path class="st1" d="M3649.2,660.4l-163.7-279.3c-14.7,2.1-28.4,3.2-43.1,3.2h-12.6v259.3h-110.2V16.8c0,0,83.9-11.6,165.8-11.6
        c132.2,0,213,57.7,213,165.9c0,85-49.3,142.8-115.5,175.4l166.9,269.8L3649.2,660.4z M3476,88.2c-25.1,0-46.1,3.1-46.1,3.1v216.3
        h11.5c75.6,0,150.1-33.6,150.1-120.8C3591.5,115.5,3542.1,88.2,3476,88.2"></path>
</g>
<g>
    <defs>
        <rect id="SVGID_5_" width="4474.5" height="660.4"></rect>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_6_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
    </clipPath>
    <polygon class="st2" points="2369.4,643.6 2369.4,11.6 2481.5,11.6 2481.5,549.1 2712.9,549.1 2712.9,643.6    "></polygon>
    <polygon class="st2" points="2146.5,11.5 2146.5,274.1 1955.7,274.1 1955.7,11.5 1844.5,11.6 1844.5,643.6 1955.7,643.6 
        1955.7,366.5 2146.5,366.5 2146.5,643.6 2257.7,643.6 2257.7,11.6     "></polygon>
    <path class="st2" d="M1678.5,540.6c-27.5,11.1-55.7,20-88.6,20.2c-32.2-0.4-59.7-7.9-82.7-21.2c-55.1-32-84.4-98.3-88.9-186.8
        c-0.4-8-0.6-16.2-0.6-24.6c0-8.4,0.2-16.6,0.6-24.6c4.5-88.5,33.7-154.9,88.9-186.8c23-13.4,50.5-20.8,82.7-21.2
        c32.9,0.2,61.1,9.1,88.6,20.2c8.9,3.6,17.8,7.4,26.7,11.2l36.7-92.4c-47.3-19.1-85.2-30.3-135.4-33c-1.1,0-2.1-0.1-3.2-0.2
        c-4.5-0.2-9.3-0.3-14.1-0.3c-24.3,0.2-46.8,2.5-67.6,6.5c-57.4,11.2-101.7,36.4-135.3,70.4l-0.4-1c-26.2,26.5-45.3,58.7-59.1,93.9
        c-0.2,0.6-0.4,1.2-0.7,1.7c-8.2,21.3-14.4,43.8-18.7,67c-0.7,3.7-1.4,7.4-2,11.1c-0.9,5.5-1.6,11-2.3,16.5
        c-0.7,5.5-1.2,11-1.7,16.5c-0.4,4.5-0.8,9-1.1,13.5c-0.6,9.5-0.9,18.9-0.9,28.5c0,0.7-0.1,1.4-0.1,2.2c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3
        c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3c0,0.7,0.1,1.4,0.1,2.2c0,9.5,0.4,19,0.9,28.5c0.3,4.5,0.7,9,1.1,13.5c0.5,5.5,1,11,1.7,16.5
        c0.7,5.5,1.4,11,2.3,16.5c0.6,3.7,1.3,7.4,2,11.1c4.3,23.2,10.5,45.6,18.7,67c0.2,0.6,0.4,1.2,0.7,1.7c13.8,35.2,33,67.4,59.1,93.9
        l0.4-1c33.6,34,77.9,59.2,135.3,70.4c20.8,4.1,43.3,6.3,67.6,6.5c4.8-0.1,9.5-0.1,14.1-0.3c1.1,0,2.1-0.1,3.2-0.2
        c50.2-2.7,88.1-13.9,135.4-33l-36.7-92.4C1696.3,533.1,1687.4,537,1678.5,540.6"></path>
</g>
<polygon points="1,848.2 1,848.2 115.8,1394.9 211.3,1394.9 334.4,982.5 335.3,982.5 458.4,1394.9 554.8,1394.9 667.7,840.8 
    575.9,840.8 506.1,1238.4 505.2,1238.4 389.5,840.8 288.5,840.8 173.7,1238.4 172.8,1238.4 97.4,830.7 "></polygon>
<rect x="785.2" y="840.8" width="98.2" height="554.1"></rect>
<polygon points="1042.2,1394.9 1042.2,840.8 1140.5,840.8 1140.5,1312 1343.4,1312 1343.4,1394.9 "></polygon>
<polygon points="1439.8,1394.9 1439.8,840.8 1538.1,840.8 1538.1,1312 1741,1312 1741,1394.9 "></polygon>
<g>
    <defs>
        <rect id="SVGID_7_" x="1" y="830.7" width="4543.1" height="578.9"></rect>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_8_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_7_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
    </clipPath>
    <path class="st3" d="M2125.7,1409.6l-143.2-244.8c-12.9,1.9-24.8,2.8-37.7,2.8h-11v227.3h-96.4V845.4c0,0,73.4-10.1,145.1-10.1
        c115.7,0,186.4,50.6,186.4,145.4c0,74.5-43.2,125.2-101,153.7l146,236.5L2125.7,1409.6z M1974.2,908c-22.1,0-40.4,2.8-40.4,2.8
        v189.6h10.1c66.1,0,131.3-29.5,131.3-105.9C2075.2,932,2032,908,1974.2,908"></path>
    <path class="st3" d="M2535.2,1405c-191.9,0-257.1-142.6-257.1-287.1c0-144.5,66.1-287.1,257.1-287.1
        c193.7,0,256.2,140.8,256.2,287.1C2791.4,1260.5,2725.3,1405,2535.2,1405 M2535.2,913.5c-103.8,0-153.4,81-153.4,204.3
        c0,125.2,48.7,204.3,153.4,204.3c103.8,0,153.3-81,153.3-204.3C2688.5,991.7,2641.7,913.5,2535.2,913.5"></path>
    <rect x="2919.8" y="840.8" class="st3" width="98.3" height="554.1"></rect>
    <path class="st3" d="M3299.1,1394.9h-122.1V845.4c0,0,79-10.1,163.4-10.1c171.7,0,281.9,84.7,281.9,248.5
        C3622.3,1284.4,3497.4,1394.9,3299.1,1394.9 M3333.1,917.2c-33.1,0-57.9,2.7-57.9,2.7v386.6h44.1c120.3,0,201.1-69.9,201.1-213.5
        C3520.4,974.3,3442.3,917.2,3333.1,917.2"></path>
    <polygon class="st3" points="3750.8,1394.9 3750.8,840.8 4034.6,840.8 4034.6,923.7 3848.1,923.7 3848.1,1070.9 4015.3,1070.9 
        4015.3,1151.9 3848.1,1151.9 3848.1,1312 4045.6,1312 4045.6,1394.9   "></polygon>
    <path class="st3" d="M4456,1409.6l-143.2-244.8c-12.9,1.9-24.8,2.8-37.7,2.8h-11v227.3h-96.4V845.4c0,0,73.5-10.1,145.1-10.1
        c115.7,0,186.4,50.6,186.4,145.4c0,74.5-43.2,125.2-101,153.7l146,236.5L4456,1409.6z M4304.5,908c-22,0-40.4,2.8-40.4,2.8v189.6
        h10.1c66.1,0,131.3-29.5,131.3-105.9C4405.5,932,4362.3,908,4304.5,908"></path>
</g>
<image xlink:href="" src="/_cache/images/cms/.40a9fb3d49ddbf65214fcd1ea70ea50f/logo_svg.svg.png" alt=""></image></svg>

    </a>

                    </div>
```

Comment: Not sure what happens exactly and who's right, but to get Chrome's behavior in FF, you can set your div's width to 100%

Comment: @Kaiido So simple. So bad that I didn't think of it myself. Thanks for your answer, it work fine.